# Replace part of string with certain characters in SQLite

Tags: string, sqlite

I need to mask a string field for example phone number "0144567890" into "014XXXX890". Only first three and last three character need to remained, others turn it into "X".Also I wish to make it dynamically which can mask any lengths of string.Thanks.

Comment: Do it in whatever language the program you're making the query from uses. SQL is not noted for its string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the maximum length of the string is say 10, 
use this `'XXXXXXXXXX'` as a pattern from which to extract the `X`s like this:

```
select 
  substr(col, 1, 3) || 
  substr('XXXXXXXXXX', 1, length(col) - 6)  || 
  substr(col, length(col) - 2)
from tablename
```

`col` is the name of the column.